# doubly linked list with dummy node

Tags: c++

I have spent much time here without progress on this implementation of the doubly linked list. I am trying to at least fix insertLast func, and I had no luck at all. Part of it is my lack of experience on how to deal with pointers in c++. Your advice is very valuable at this point. When execute I will get 0 as the size of the list.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node {
public:
int data;
Node *prev, *next;
Node(int x,Node *p,Node *q) {
    data = x; prev = p; next = q;
}
};
public class Position :public Node {

//};

class List {
public:
Node *head;
int size;
public:
List() {
    head = new Node(NULL,NULL,NULL);
    head->prev = head;
    head->next = head;
    size = 0;

}
int Size(){
    return List().size;
}
void insertFirst(int x)
{
    insertBefore(first(), x);

}
void insertLast(int x)
{
    insertAfter(last(), x);

}

void insertAfter(Node *p, int x) {
    Node *q = new Node(x,p,p->next);
    p->next->prev = q;
    p->next = q;
    size += 1;
}
void insertBefore(Node *p, int x) {
    Node *q = new Node(x,p->prev,p);
    p->prev->next = q;
    p->prev = q;
    size += 1;
}
void insertAtRank(int rank, int x)
{
    insertBefore(toPosition(rank), x);
}
void remove(Node *p) {
    p->prev->next = p->next;
    p->next->prev = p->prev;
    p->prev = p->next = NULL;
    size -= 1;
}
void removeAtRank(int rank)
{
    remove(toPosition(rank));
}
int element(Node *p)
{
    return p->data;
}
int elementAtRank(int rank)
{
    return toPosition(rank)->data;
}
int toRank(Node *p) {
    int r = 0;
    for (Node *q = first(); q != p; q = q->next) r += 1;
    return r;
}
Node *toPosition(int rank) {
    if (rank > size){
        throw "exception";
    }
    Node *q = first();
    for (int r = 0; r != rank; r += 1){
        q = q->next;
        return q;
    }
}


Node *first() { return head->next; }
Node *last() { return head->prev; }
Node *after(Node *p) { return p->next; }
Node *before(Node *p) { return p->prev; }
bool isEmpty() { return head->next == head; }

Node *removeLast(){
    if (last() == NULL){
        throw "exception";
    }
    Node *p = last();
    p->prev->next = p->next;
    p->next->prev = p->prev;
    p->prev = p->next = NULL;
    return p;
}

};


void main(){
int x;
List l;
int a[]{163, 179, 103, 91, 404,
    531, 745, 405, 686,
    858, 898, 926, 266, 867, 865,
    91, 103, 163, 179, 2,
    66, 404, 405, 531, 686, 745,
    858, 865, 867, 898, 926};
int size = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    l.insertLast(i);

}

for (int j = 0; j < l.Size(); j++){
    cout << l.elementAtRank(j) << endl;
}
cout << l.Size();
cin >> x;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but SO is not meant for what you want. You should ask something more precise about your code.

Comment: @mokarab Funcion Size should look like int Size(){
    return size;
} Otherewise it will always return 0.

Comment: You could at least mention what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to at least fix insertLast func

Your inserLast() looks fine. Try the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node {
public:
int data;
Node *prev, *next;
Node(int x,Node *p,Node *q) {
    data = x; prev = p; next = q;
}
};

class List {
public:
Node *head;
int size;
public:
List() {
    head = new Node(0,NULL,NULL);
    head->prev = head;
    head->next = head;
    size = 0;

}
int Size(){
    return size;
}
void insertFirst(int x)
{
    insertBefore(first(), x);

}
void insertLast(int x)
{
    insertAfter(last(), x);

}

void insertAfter(Node *p, int x) {
    Node *q = new Node(x,p,p->next);
    p->next->prev = q;
    p->next = q;
    size += 1;
}
void insertBefore(Node *p, int x) {
    Node *q = new Node(x,p->prev,p);
    p->prev->next = q;
    p->prev = q;
    size += 1;
}
void insertAtRank(int rank, int x)
{
    insertBefore(toPosition(rank), x);
}
void remove(Node *p) {
    p->prev->next = p->next;
    p->next->prev = p->prev;
    p->prev = p->next = NULL;
    size -= 1;
}
void removeAtRank(int rank)
{
    remove(toPosition(rank));
}
int element(Node *p)
{
    return p->data;
}
int elementAtRank(int rank)
{
    return toPosition(rank)->data;
}
int toRank(Node *p) {
    int r = 0;
    for (Node *q = first(); q != p; q = q->next) r += 1;
    return r;
}
Node *toPosition(int rank) {
    if (rank > size){
        throw "exception";
    }
    Node *q = first();
    for (int r = 0; r != rank; r += 1){
        q = q->next;

    }
    return q;
}


Node *first() { return head->next; }
Node *last() { return head->prev; }
Node *after(Node *p) { return p->next; }
Node *before(Node *p) { return p->prev; }
bool isEmpty() { return head->next == head; }

Node *removeLast(){
    if (last() == NULL){
        throw "exception";
    }
    Node *p = last();
    p->prev->next = p->next;
    p->next->prev = p->prev;
    p->prev = p->next = NULL;
    return p;
}

};


void main(){
int x;
List l;
int a[]{163, 179, 103, 91, 404,
    531, 745, 405, 686,
    858, 898, 926, 266, 867, 865,
    91, 103, 163, 179, 2,
    66, 404, 405, 531, 686, 745,
    858, 865, 867, 898, 926};
int size = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    l.insertLast(i);
}

for (int j = 0; j < l.Size(); j++){
    cout << l.elementAtRank(j) << endl;
}
cout << l.Size();
cin >> x;
}
```

**Changes I made**:

- Removed the *vague* class Position : public Node
- int Size() { return size; }
- Node* toPosition (int rank) {...} - moved the return statement in the end

**N.B.**: I did not check other parts of your code. I just made your code compile correctly and work as expected, because "you were trying to at least fix insertLast func"

Comment: if my answer helped you, please accept it. [Check this link to learn how to accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: the change that you have made is really essential, however the insertLast still not working.

Comment: ya..,it is working now, I was using a different file that is implemented a little different.